# Empty response from rrule.between

Tags: javascript, node.js, rrule

I'm using [rrule](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule) to work with recurrence tasks.

Everything works fine (like expected), except when I use the `between` method.
I want to get the only the instances between today and tomorrow from this string rule

`const stringRule = "DTSTART:20200515T163000Z RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=5;INTERVAL=1;WKST=MO"
 let ruleobj = rrules.rrulestr(stringrule);
 let instances = ruleobj.between(new Date(Date.UTC(2020, 5, 19)), new Date(Date.UTC(2020, 5, 20)) );`

The method `ruleobj.all` returns all instances for this stringrule.

`"instances": [
            "2020-05-15T16:05:00.000Z",
            "2020-05-16T16:05:00.000Z",
            "2020-05-17T16:05:00.000Z",
            "2020-05-18T16:05:00.000Z",
            "2020-05-19T16:05:00.000Z",
            "2020-05-20T16:05:00.000Z"
        ]`

So, the `between` method should be return

`["2020-05-19T16:05:00.000Z",
  "2020-05-20T16:05:00.000Z"]`

but return `[]`

Yeah, I can filter the filter instances (Actually I did), but... How does the method work?. Why return empty?